# Double integral definition

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I don't understand the definition of double integral.
For instance in the functions with single variable the definite integral was defined as Riemannian sum as: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(c_k)\delta x_k$$ In which I could assume $f(c_k)$ as the height and $\delta x_k$ as the width of the rectangles we're going to calculate the sum of but for the double integration in the region $R$ we've got the definition:
$$\lim_{\delta A\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k,y_k)\delta A_k $$
Now I can assume the $\delta A$ to be the surface of small rectangles which cover the region $R$.Then what $f(x_k,y_k)$ supposed to be?
I'm trying to learn by analogy that $f(c_k)$ was assumed to be the **height** but now what is the $f(x_k,y_k)$ **supposed to be** in the double integral definition?
Thanks in advance
P.S: ***Notice*** that I'm trying to find out what $f(x_k,y_k)$ tries to represent when we're trying to find the **surface** of region $R$ **not the volume**!

Answer (score 2):

$f(x_k,y_k)$ represents the height of the right rectangular prism (ie. the box) of base area $\delta A_k$.  The sum of the volume of all of these boxes will approximate the volume under the surface $z=f(x,y)$ and above $R$.

Comment: You're trying to calculate volume, what if we try to calculate the surface?then what would the f(x,y) represent?

Comment: @MrWho: It could also represent the density of the flat material at that point.  Then the integral would represent the total mass of the material.